# Adding layer to GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, geopackage, qgsvectorlayer, writers

How to add layers (vector or raster to an existing GeoPackage)?

While loading an existing layer of a GeoPackage is quite trivial:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

path = '/home/matteo/geopackage.gpkg|layername={}'.format('admin')
iface.addVectorLayer(path, 'admin', 'ogr')
```

I couldn't find information about adding them via PyQGIS.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 14):

You need to use [`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a0fb1b773dbe4030890a04310aff4728b). If you store one layer per GPKG file you just need:

### QGIS 3:

```py
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorFileWriter

# get layer list by one of:
lyrs = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
lyrs = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()

# select layer
lyr = lyrs[0]
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, r"C:\gisData\layer.gpkg")
```

### QGIS 2:

```
# imports
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorFileWriter

# get layer list by one of:
lyrs = iface.mapCanvas().layers() # OR
lyrs = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()

# select layer
lyr = lyrs[0]
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, r"C:\gisData\layer.gpkg")
```

If you want save more than one layer in GeoPackage file you should set additional options.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter

for lyr in filter(lambda l: l.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer, lyrs):
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
    options.layerName = "_".join(lyr.name().split(' '))
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, gpkgPath, options)
    if _writer:
        print(lyr.name(), _writer)
```

PyQGIS should have similar interface for raster layers. In my opinion easiest way to find out is to install IPyConsole plugin and use [PyQGIS API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master).

Comment: `QgsMapLayerRegistry` is gone in QGIS 3, but `writeAsVectorFormat` should still be there.
Sidenote, there is also the `QgsVectorLayerExporter` class available.

Answer (score 13):

### Write a layer to a GeoPackage

The easiest way to save a vector layer to GeoPackage is to use the ["Save vector features to file"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#save-vector-features-to-file) algorithm, available from QGIS 3.16 on.

```py
import processing

params = {'INPUT': existing_layer,
          'OUTPUT': '/tmp/new_gpkg.gpkg',
          'LAYER_NAME': 'new_layer_name'}
processing.run("native:savefeatures", params)
```

Note that you can pass additional [GDAL/OGR options](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#dataset-creation-options) by passing `DATASOURCE_OPTIONS` and `LAYER_OPTIONS` parameters.

**Warning:** *If you pass a path to an existing GeoPackage as `OUTPUT` parameter, this algorithm will replace your GeoPackage by a new one!!!*

### Adding an additional layer to an existing GeoPackage

**Option 1**

If you want to add a layer to an existing GeoPackage (and still preserve other existing layers!), you can use the GDAL's ["Convert format"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#convert-format) algorithm in this way:

```py
import processing

params = {'INPUT': existing_layer,
          'OPTIONS':'-update -nln my_new_layer_name',
          'OUTPUT':'/tmp/existing_db.gpkg'}
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", params)
```

Where **-update** indicates the existing GeoPackage shouldn't be overwritten but updated, and **-nln** (optional) indicates the layer name you want your `existing_layer` to have when created into the existing GeoPackage.

**Option 2**

You could also use the ["Package layers"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#package-layers) algorithm, which allows you to add several layers at once, in this way:

```py
import processing

params = {'LAYERS': [layer1, layer2],
          'OUTPUT': '/tmp/existing_db.gpkg',
          'OVERWRITE': False,  # Important!
          'SAVE_STYLES': False,
          'SAVE_METADATA': False,
          'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY': False}
processing.run("native:package", params)
```

**Note:** *Set the rest of parameters as you like, but the `OVERWRITE` one should be set to `False` if you want to update the existing GeoPackage.*

Comment: This seems to be directly creating a new geopackage from an existing layer. Is there a way to add an existing layer to an existing geopackage?

Comment: Just try passing as OUTPUT an existing GeoPackage file path, as the answers also suggests.

Comment: Yes, I used an existing gpkg as output and got an error message (it attempts to create a new gpkg with that name, and throws an error since it already exists). I was able to figure it out just now, though -- to add a new layer to an existing gpkg, "qgis:package" should be used instead.

Comment: You're actually right. I edited my answer to show a solution for your use case.

Answer (score 7):

I have investigated [this code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgsrasterfilewriter.py) an create a script like it works very well for exporting raster layer to GeoPackage:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRasterFileWriter, QgsRasterPipe, QgsRasterProjector

ds = ogr.Open(self.projectGpkg, True)
source = QgsRasterLayer(layerSource, 'rasterLayer', 'gdal')

if source.isValid():
    provider = source.dataProvider()
    fw = QgsRasterFileWriter(self.projectGpkg)
    fw.setOutputFormat('gpkg')
    fw.setCreateOptions(["RASTER_TABLE=" + str(tableName), 'APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES'])

    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    if pipe.set(provider.clone()) is True:
        projector = QgsRasterProjector()
        projector.setCrs(provider.crs(), provider.crs())
        if pipe.insert(2, projector) is True:
            if fw.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(), provider.ySize(), provider.extent(), provider.crs()) == 0:
                print("ok")
            else:
                print("error")
ds = None
```

For reading raster layer in GeoPackage:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

rlayer = QgsRasterLayer('GPKG:' + str(self.projectGpkg) + ':tableName', "layerName")
```

Answer (score 1):

For raster layers, use the GDAL's ["Translate (convert format)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#translate-convert-format) algorithm:

```py
import processing

params = { 
    'COPY_SUBDATASETS' : False, 
    'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 
    'EXTRA' : '-co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=name_of_layer', 
    'INPUT' : layer_to_add, 
    'NODATA' : None, 
    'OPTIONS' : '', 
    'OUTPUT' : 'existing.gpkg', 
    'TARGET_CRS' : None 
}
processing.run("gdal:translate", params)
```

For vector layers see [the answer from @GermánCarrillo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401032/99589).