# Creating GeoPackage file with one layer (or more) named different from file name using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, geopackage, qgsvectorlayer, writers

I want to create geopackage file using PyQGIS (for example database.gpkg) with one layer (named "myLayer").
I've tried this

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(fileName, 'UTF-8', layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Unknown, QgsProject.instance().crs(), 'GPKG', newLayer='myLayer')
```

but got an error:

> ```
> ('newLayer' is an unknown keyword argument)
> ```

I can't use `writeAsVectorFormatV2` because I need to create file first and than add it to QGIS.

Comment: @JGH no, this answer for saving exiting layers to geopackage and i know how to do this. But i need to create a geopackage first and then add it to Qgis.

Comment: Germán Carrillo's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401032/84870) does just  that: in a single step, it creates the geopackage and saves the layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution. It works for me:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsCoordinateTransformContext

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.layerName = 'myLayer'
transformContext = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(fileName, layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Unknown, QgsProject.instance().crs(), transformContext, options)
```