# 'Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR error: )' error when adding layer to GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, geopackage, qgsvectorlayer, writers

While running the following code:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = canvas.currentLayer()
print(layer.name())

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer

#options.layerName = "_".join(layer.name().split(' '))
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "C:/Users/ilyasse2.0/Documents/SQRLAND/hh.gpkg", options)
print(writer)
```

I got this error:

> ```
> (2, 'Opening of data source in update mode failed (OGR error: )')
> ```

The layer is created by with:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", 'layerName', "memory")
```

I tried to use this solution: [Adding layers to GeoPackage using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285346/adding-layers-to-geopackage-using-pyqgis) but it is not working for me.

Comment: i have used this solution   : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285346/adding-layers-to-geopackage-using-pyqgis  but it's not working

Comment: You can do that by using the processing algorithm `native:savefeatures`. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401032/4972)

Comment: i believe that it will only work for one layer i want to add multiple layers

Comment: Oh, that's new info that the question does not mention. Additionally, `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()` also works for a single layer, but you have Python to iterate.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a GeoPackage or if you already have a GeoPackage with layers in it and want to add another layer to it you can use this example where I create a memory layer with a process (extent of a layer) and then add it to the GeoPackage:

```py
import processing
from os.path import abspath, isfile, join
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorFileWriter

path = abspath("path/to/layer")
gpgk_name = 'test.gpkg'
gpkg_path = join(path, gpgk_name) # your geopackage

polygon_layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = processing.run("qgis:polygonfromlayerextent",{
                                 'INPUT': polygon_layer,
                                 'ROUND_TO': 0,
                                 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                 })
layer = extent['OUTPUT'] # your memory layer

context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()

if isfile(gpkg_path):
    options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
options.layerName = layer.name()
options.fileEncoding = layer.dataProvider().encoding()
options.driverName = "GPKG"

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, gpkg_path, context, options)
```

At the begining I had this, a GeoPackage with three layers:

[image: before the code]

After creating the extent as a memory layer and add it to the GeoPackage I have this:

[image: after the code]

If you want to overwrite an existing GeoPackage you need to delete this condition:

```py
from os.path import isfile

if isfile(gpkg_path):
    options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
```

Comment: It seems like the `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2()` function is deprecated and gives a warning. However, i used the code above except i was using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3()` which removes the deprecation warning - function arguments and result seem to be the same...

Comment: @Valentin yes since version 3.20, I edited my response, previous version needs to use  `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2()`

Answer (score 0):

These PyQGIS solutions seem very convoluted. You can just use GeoPandas to write a new layer to an existing GeoPackage like this:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(#whatever your source is#)
gpkg_file = 'name.gpkg'
new_layer = 'newlayer'
gdf.to_file(gpkg_file, layer=new_layer, driver="GPKG")
```