# Set FID field name in a GPKG processing algorithm ouput

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a standalone pyqgis script that uses processing algorithms. The final output is a GPKG layer, and I want to define the name of the FID field (that by default is `fid`).

The relevant code is something like this:

```py
import processing

processing.run("native:buffer", {
    "INPUT": "/data/input.gpkg|layername=input",
    "OUTPUT": "/data/output.gpkg",
    "DISTANCE": 10,
})
```

This generates an `output.gpkg` with a primary key called `fid`, but I want to use another name.

Using two steps, following [the advice of this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401032/4177) I can get the desired output:

```py
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing

outputs = {}

outputs["buffer"] = processing.run(
    "native:buffer",
    {
        "INPUT": "/data/input.gpkg|layername=input",
        "OUTPUT": QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,,
        "DISTANCE": 10,
    },
)

outputs["savefeatures"] = processing.run(
    "native:savefeatures",
    {
        "INPUT": outputs["buffer"]["OUTPUT"],
        "OUTPUT": "/data/output.gpkg",
        "LAYER_OPTIONS": "FID=id;",
    },
)
```

But, it will be nice if there is a way to do it in just one step, something like:

```
`"OUTPUT": "/data/output.gpkg?FID=id"`
```

that does not work.

Comment: Can you rename it with refactor fields?

Comment: I know that what should happen is to pass the layer creation option `-lco FID=id` for GDAL  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html. Unfortunately I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks both. I edited my question to explain how can be done i a two step process, and reframe the question a bit.